# Twilio conferenceSid from callSid

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter, twilio-conference

I have been using Twilio with a node and Angular project to build a call centre. All the incoming and outgoing calls are made to conference call to make it easy to add participants for transfer call etc.

In the Angular project, I have been using Twilio device to initialise a connection to accepts calls. The parameters that I always receive from the clinet are `from`, `to`, `callSid` and `accountSid`. I need to find the `conferenceSid` to add a participant to the call. Is there a way I can get the `conferenceSid` with just the `callSid`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conference eventing to capture the ConferenceSID the participants are joining. However, not clear on the call flow of how your are connecting participants into the conference.

[TwiML™ Voice: Conference - statusCallbackEvent](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-statusCallbackEvent)